# Работа с HTTP в Mono. Зависает HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

Здравствуйте. Разрабатываю консольное приложение в MonoDevelop под Ubuntu.
Отправляю http-запросы к серверу. Ответ читаю следующим образом:

```
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
{
     bodyResp = stream.ReadToEnd();
     stream.Close();
}
resp.Close();
```

Несколько запросов проходят хорошо, но потом на таком же запросе GetResponseStream() виснет.
Для справки: под Windows в .Net Runtime ни разу такого не наблюдалось.
Есть предположение, что stream виснет из-за того, что сервер дает Error 503 Unknown. Он действительно частенько выдает такое. Но, повторюсь, на винде все гладко, и насколько мне известно там stream при такой ошибке возвращает null.
Сокращать время между запросами нет смысла. Потому что сервер гружу не я один, и эти ошибки - нормальное явление. Вот только Mono так не считает.
Может кто знает как можно переписать код, чтобы в случае, если сервер дает ошибку, в bodyResp записалось null? Или может дело не в ошибке, возвращаемой сервером?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась, когда отключил KeepAlive. Видимо в mono поддержка соединения с сервером реализована неважно. Спасибо тем двум ребятам, что откликнулись и постарались помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Поставь `using` на response.

Количество одновременных запросов ограничено, но может настраиваться. Если у тебя остаются неуничтоженные запросы (а using'а нет, значит при исключении закрытие не происходит) будут мешать отправке новых.

Comment: Разместил using. Сначала решил, что помогло, но, оказалось, просто повезло и выполнилась длительная серия удачных запросов. Есть еще идеи?

Comment: @orl412, сколько одновременных запросов посылается? Проблемы возникают именно при исключениях?

Comment: Сравни расстановку using'ов с этим: http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?p=6770380#p6770380

Comment: Вообще, будут работать 2 потока. Но виснет даже пока второй поток бездействует. То есть потоки идут последовательно, один за другим. Дело в том, что исключение не создается. Как я понял, поток просто зависает. Когда пытался отследить, в каком месте он зависает, понял, что на GetResponseStream.

Comment: Вот мой using, я полагаю, он аналогичен Вашем примеру.
using(HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    {
                 using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
                 {
                     bodyResp = stream.ReadToEnd();
                     stream.Close();
                 }
     resp.Close();
    }

Comment: @orl412 Исключение должно бы выдаваться. Если он просто ждёт истечения таймаута, то, естественно, объект жив. Попробуй уменьшить таймаут в свойствах запроса.

Comment: Ох, у меня же все в блоках try/catch было. Мозг совсем кипит уже. Извиняюсь. Выдает исключение: The remote server returned an error: (429) Unknown.

Comment: Черт, но ведь это уже другое. Я говорил, что сервер может возвращать такую ошибку. Блоки try/catch просто избавляли меня от исключений подобного рода. Сейчас без блоков try/catch я тестирую и когда таких исключений не наблюдается (везет, что сервер все запросы отрабатывает), то рано или поздно поток виснет

Comment: 1. [HttpWebRequest.Timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) 2. [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Поставил таймаут 5 секунд, лимит подключений увеличил до 20. Не помогло. Виснет и все тут. Не судьба что ли...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте скачивать данные `WebClient`. Выглядит более лаконично.
Если нужны байты:

```
var myWebClient = new WebClient();
byte[] myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData (remoteUri);
```

или если нужен текст:

```
string reply = myWebClient.DownloadString (remoteUri);
```

Так же доступна новая библиотека [HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) для веб-запросов.

Comment: Спасибо за WebClient. Действительно удобнее. Но это не помогло. Все также виснет и через минуты 2 дает исключение "The operation has timed out." на строчке: HtmlResult = webClient.DownloadString(URL); Хотя я поставил таймаут 5 секунд. Видимо, тут проблема не в том, как я организую запросы. Но в чем тогда...